# I want to keep 2 values for next save from preivous save. MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller

User enters PWS (public water system), LabID. Then clicks Save button.
I would like these values to populate the new input form that right now gets emptied out on a succesful save.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PWS, new { @autofocus = "autofocus", @style="width:50px", @maxlength="5" })
```

Controller ActionResult
First time through:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddColiform(string sortorder)
{
    int batchid;
    batchid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ThisBatch"]);
    //Session["ThisBatch"] = batchid;
    ViewBag.Methods = FillMethods();
    ViewBag.Latest = (from m in _db.BactiBucket
                      where m.Batch_ID == batchid
                      select m).ToList();
    ViewBag.ThisBatch = batchid;
    return View(new BactiBucket());
}
```

When Save button clicked:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddColiform(BactiBucket bucket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //FIRST RECORD SAVED FOR USER CREATES BATCH, OTHERWISE BATCH IS ZERO
        if (Session["ThisBatch"].Equals(0))
        {
            var newbatchid = CheckAndMakeBatchIfNone();
            Session["ThisBatch"] = newbatchid;
            bucket.Batch_ID = newbatchid;
        }
        _db.AddToBactiBucket(bucket);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AddColiform");
    }
    ViewBag.Methods = FillMethods();
    int batchid;
    batchid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ThisBatch"]);
    ViewBag.ThisBatch = batchid;
    ViewBag.Latest = (from m in _db.BactiBucket
                      where m.Batch_ID == batchid
                      select m).ToList();
    return View(bucket);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you do `RedirectToAction("AddColiform");`?

Comment: not sure. this stuff makes me cross eyed.
In the first ActionResult the "Viewbag.Latest" builds a list of all samples entered for that batch, latest one at the top.
That shows up when form first opens.
I want to somehow store the PWS and LabID that are being saved and put them in the TextBoxFor again for next record.

Comment: Currently after `SaveChanges()` you do a redirect to the GET method which displays a new `BactiBucket` (with default properties). Are you wanting that view to display an edit for for a new `BactiBucket` which already has some properties already set?

Comment: Yes, but it's not an edit screen. I have an edit screen that works. What it is is a new Add screen that pre-populates the previous PWS and Lab ID. Labs send in a bunch of water samples for the same water system and it becomes redundant to enter the PWS and LabID over and over. This was request from the client.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what your saying

Comment: Visualize this. You have a stack of paper with information on them.
Everyone of these papers have the same PWS number and same LabID. When you save the information on this form, you want those 2 values to stick around for the next row you save.

Comment: Your going to have to add your models and the view so I can understand just what properties your trying to persist.

Comment: MS Access textboxes have a property called "PreviousValue".
In PHP, ASP, ASPX I would get the 2 values and store in persistent Session right before INSERT statement or right after POST. In ASPX I could also use ViewState. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters to your GET method in the redirect, and use ths values to set the properties of your model (note its not clear why your method has a parameter `string sortorder` when you never use it)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddColiform(string sortorder, string PWS, string LabID)
{
  ....
  BactiBucket model = new BactiBucket() { PWS = PWS, LabID = LabID };
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddColiform(BactiBucket bucket)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ....
    return RedirectToAction("AddColiform", new { PWS = bucket.PWS, LabID = bucket.LabID });
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: ah, sortorder. hmmm. I think I was going to or am going to use it for the ViewBag.Latest which are rows of all samples entered in the user's current batch. This is for their reference. I must sort the list some other way. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if it was a snake it would have bit me.

In the declaration of the ActionResult I pass the values of the textboxes to the controller. It comes in with the Post action. (PWS and LabID are the names of the inputs).

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult AddColiform(BactiBucket bucket, string PWS, string LabID)
```

Then right before the return RedirectToAction("AddColiform");

I set Session variables for each value:
Session["PWS"]=PWS;
Session["LabID"]=LabID;

of course I might use ViewBag.PWS and ViewBag.LabID

Then, when returning and building the new Add Record form,
I populate the @Value of each textbox respectfully:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PWS, new {@Value=Session["PWS"], @autofocus = "autofocus", @style="width:50px", @maxlength="5" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LabID, new {@Value=Session["LabID"], @style="width:150px", @maxlength="20" })
```

Since I haven't run this code I know I will have to check if Session objects aren't null. Or ViewBag objects. Or set them to "" first time through.

I got this from [this forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1610900.aspx?Pass%20textbox%20value%20to%20controller%20class)

Comment: Oh dear! If you wanting to pass values to the GET method, then add 2 parameters `int LabID and `string PWS` and in the POST method, return RedirectToAction("AddColiform", new { LabID = x, PWS = y }); and in the GET method, initialize you model and set the properties based on the parameter values before you pass it to the view.

Comment: whoa! you are right!
In the Get ActionResult I put this: -- public ActionResult AddColiform(string sortorder, string PWS, string LabID)--
At the Post ActionResult declaration line I put this-- public ActionResult AddColiform(BactiBucket bucket,string PWS, string LabID)--
In the Post ActionResult, after SaveChanges I put this --  return RedirectToAction("AddColiform",new {PWS = PWS, LabID = LabID });-- I didn't have to do anything else, it just showed up on new Add Page.--If you want to make your comment an Answer, I will check it as the answer.

Comment: But. . . I am still wondering what is so cryptic about the title to my question. 
" I want to keep 2 values for next save from preivous save. MVC 4"